# Error while installing kumofs

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, makefile

I'm trying to install kumofs (https://github.com/etolabo/kumofs) on docker, but I'm getting following error while running configure command.

Any help in this regards is highly appriciated.

```
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in '.'.
libtoolize: copying file './ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: You should add the contents of the following files to      'aclocal.m4':
libtoolize:   '/usr/share/aclocal/libtool.m4'
libtoolize:   '/usr/share/aclocal/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize:   '/usr/share/aclocal/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize:   '/usr/share/aclocal/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize:   '/usr/share/aclocal/lt~obsolete.m4'
libtoolize: Remember to add 'LT_INIT' to configure.in.
libtoolize: Consider adding 'AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])' to configure.in,
libtoolize: and rerunning libtoolize and aclocal.
libtoolize: Consider adding '-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not  'configure.in'
autom4te: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /usr/local/m4
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
autom4te: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /usr/local/m4
autoheader: '/usr/bin/autom4te' failed with exit status: 1
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not  'configure.in'
autom4te: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /usr/local/m4
automake: error: autoconf failed with exit status: 1
autom4te: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /usr/local/m4
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `m4` package:

```
sudo apt-get install m4
```

Comment: I have already added the m4 package.
I unset the M4 variable and it worked for me.

Comment: Are you sure its version 1.4 or later?

Answer (score 0):

Unset M4 variable and it worked for me.
Before : M4=/usr/local/m4 (was causing error)
After : M4=  (got fixed)

But now I'm facing another issue.
I'm configuring kumofs with following command.
    root@37506a75b0ac:/home/kumofs# ./configure --with-  msgpack=/usr/local/lib/libmsgpackc.so

I'm getting following error:

```
checking if tcadb is enabled...
checking for main in -lstdc++... no
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... no
configure: error: Can't find pthread library
```

I have already installed libpthread-stubs0-dev

Answer (score 0):

---

Kumofs build requirements : The c++ compiler ( Package name = g++ or gcc-c++ ).
The "**libstdc++**-[version]-dev(el)" will be installed as dependency for g++.

And **msgpack**(-0.5.7) https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/msgpack >>  http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/m/msgpack/msgpack_0.5.7.orig.tar.gz
And '**ragel**' . And **tokyocabinet** : http://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/tokyocabinet/tokyocabinet/1.4.32/tokyocabinet-1.4.32.tar.gz

---